# Sqlite libsqlite3.so.0 Not Found

Tags: linux, sqlite, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I'm trying to get sqlite3 to work on ubuntu linux. I first tried to download sqlite3 but was given an error about multiple versions. I then deleted libsqlite3.so.0 and another counterpart to that using gksudo natalie, which was recommended. I then reinstalled the two rpm files...I now have eight of them and the whole thing is blowing up and I'm frustrated and tired. Is there anyone who can tell me how to clean install the entire thing, sqlite3, rpms and all? I've just about had it. This is the error I'm getting now.

```
sqlite3 mydatabase.db
sqlite3: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlite3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**WARNING** - Purging packages can be risky. You might try install before purging/install.

You might be using a different version of Ubuntu but chances are this will work
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1883976

```
sudo apt-get purge sqlite3 sqlite3-doc libsqlite3-0

sudo apt-get install sqlite3 sqlite3-doc
```

if you can use a terminal this should be fast and easy.

Comment: This command is very dangerous, it removed a lot of gnome libraries and completely broken my linux.

Comment: @Vistritium Same thing happened to me, but I was trying to update nvidia video driver for linux. Someone online listed a command to follow, it was a big mistake. It completely destroyed my linux system. Autoremove, remove or purge commands are very dangerous if you are not careful.

Comment: Same happened to me. DO NOT USE the command above. It's dangerous and will destroy your installation.

Comment: Same for me, luckily I got prompted. It took a long time just preparing the list of packages it was going to remove. I flagged this answer, I think it should be removed (and should have been removed by the author after seeing the comments.)

Comment: Sounds like a valuable lesson was learned. Don't blindly copy paste answers from SO

Answer (score 2):

If sqlite3 is not installed, simply installing it may resolve your issue -

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```